# How to monitor web access in my network

Tags: proxy, web, cache, web-filtering

Is there a free alternative to something like [Webmarshal](http://www.m86security.com/products/web_security/webmarshal.asp)?

I would like to log every website that is accessed from my network. Just logging – no blocking or filtering, but I guess most of the applications come with the functionality anyway.

I have tried IPCop but development has stopped and it has a firewall which I don't need (and it can't be turned off). Caching would be icing on the cake but not required. I can make small changes to the network although if it's transparent, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I have used the Squid Proxy for this. It can operate in transparent mode if need be, but that is more work. Easiest is the configure the clients to use the proxy and configure the router/firewall to block HTTP access from any IP_address but that of the Proxy.